# Best effort retries in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have an RDD that I need to map over a task that can fail

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
rdd.map(a_task_that_can_fail)
```

Is there a way to set spark to run the task in best efforts basis. My desired behaviour is:

- Retry the task 5 times, if fails after 5 times, return None, if succeeds then return the result

Comment: Spark has a built in retry configuration parameter

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "set spark"?
What about the python code?
Or do you mean a failure like running out of memory?

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3, 0])

def try_and_return(x, number_of_trys = 5):
    try_number = 0;
    return_value = None;

    while (try_number < number_of_trys):
        try:
            return_value = 1.0/x
            break
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            try_number += 1
    return return_value


print rdd.map(lambda x: try_and_return(x)).collect()
```

[1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333, None]